# Want to create user-dependent Drop Down in Google Form

Tags: arrays, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

I am creating a Google Form for the managers in my company where they have to write the feedback of their reportees. 
For example. If there are 3 managers. **Mr. x@company.com has 4 direct reportees**, **Mr. y@company.com has 3 direct reportees**, **Mr. z@company.com has 2 direct reportees**.

Now if anyone from the above logs in the Google Form to share his input, the first question that I want is the drop down to choose their reportee. I want to create a dynamic dropdown.

Let's say if Mr. X logs in to fill the form, he only sees his reportee's name in the dropdown and can select one of them to write a feedback about him/her in the next question. Similarly if Y logs in, he sees his reportees and likewise.
I tried FormRanger Addon, but only gives static dropdown and not dependent one.

How to go about this?

Comment: It's not possible.